# Send Image to Whatsapp from angular web

Tags: angular, whatsapp

I want to send an image to WhatsApp from a Angular based website.

I know how to have a text message sent to WhatsApp by creating an anchor with a href as below;

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hi, this is a test" target="_blank">Send by WhatsApp</a>
```

But I don't know how to same or similar so as to send images from my Angular website to WhatsApp.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to use the relatively new `navigator.share` API to achieve this. This wouldn't be limited to just WhatsApp, but allow sharing to any apps that the user has installed with appropriate share handlers

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/05/web-share-files

Not sure if there is a deeplink alternative that would provide better legacy support for whatsappd specifically

Comment: But this is only use for Android Chrome.. no?

Comment: The basic web share functionality should be supported on recent versions of both android and ios based on https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-share - it seems like the files extension may only be supported by android at this stage.

I can't find anything in the whatsapp documentation suggesting alternative ways to share image data directly to whatsapp from a web browser